# NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

when I try to fetch the result from the JSON result. It throws the following exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa006449656c6f526'
```

My code.

```
 NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  mutableData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
 for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {   
  NSString *firstname = [dataDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
  }
```

The above code throws an `NSException`.

My JSON response looks like this.

```
{
"IsExternal": 0,
"LoginId": 4,
"EmployeeId": 223,
"FirstName": "GharValueCA",
"RoleId": 4,
"LastName": null,
"Mobile": null,
"AgencyId": 100,
"BranchId": 74
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to ` You are using an `NSDictionary` method (`objectForKey:`) on a `NSString` object. That's what is saying the error. `jsonObjects` is a `NSDictionary`, no for loop on it is needed, while your code suggest it's a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 9):

According to the definition of JSON, each JSON contains one object (which can be a collection type that contains other objects). In your case, your text starts with "{", so that's a dictionary. A *single* dictionary.

So `NSJSONSerialization`, when it reads that file, gives you back an `NSDictionary` containing values under keys like IsExternal, FirstName etc.

However, your code uses `for( ... in ... )` on that dictionary (which, according to `NSDictionary` documentation, will iterate over the keys in the dictionary, which are strings), but then you treat those strings as if they were dictionaries *again*.

So instead of looping over the dictionary, you should just use the dictionary in `jsonObjects` directly, by calling something like `-objectForKey:` on it.

Comment: Would be curious why the downvoter voted this down? Something incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

There is a misunderstanding:

`jsonObjects` **is** already the dictionary, assign the deserialized object immediately to `dataDict`.

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mutableData 
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil]; 
                  // mutableContainers in not needed to read the JSON
```

The enumerated objects are strings, numbers or `<null>`. You called `objectForKey:` on a string which caused the error.

Get the name directly (no loop)

```
NSString *firstname = dataDict[@"FirstName"];
```

or you can enumerate the dictionary

```
 for (NSString *key in dataDict) {
    NSLog(@"key:%@ - value:%@", key, dict[key]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
[jsonObjects objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
```

to get the FirstName value.

Below lines of code returns you (probably) a `NSDictionary`, so this is the container that stores all of your json values.

```
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
              mutableData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Comment: objectForKey would be a string, in objective C string is not like " ", it should be @" "

Comment: You should really be using short hand for this via `jsonObjects[@"FirstName"];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if ([jsonObjects isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSString *firstname = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
}
```

as your 'jsonObjects' is of generic type 'id' so just check that whether it is of NSDictionary type and then in if-block you can directly access it by objectForKey:

Answer (score -2):

try this code, hope it help,

```
   id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                      mutableData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    if([jsonObjects respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]){
         NSString *firstname = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
    }
```

Comment: This will just make it do nothing, ever, with the given input.